# Select a NON-DISTINCT column in a query that return distincts rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following query returns the results that I need but I have to add the ID of the row to then update it. If I add the ID directly in the select statement it will return me more results then I need because each ID is unique so the DISTINCT statement see the line as unique.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ucpse.MemberID, ucpse.ProductID, ucpse.UserID
FROM UserCustomerProductSalaryExceptions as ucpse
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
            FROM UserCustomerProductSalaryExceptions as upcse2 
            WHERE ucpse.userid = upcse2.userid AND ucpse.MemberID = upcse2.MemberID AND ucpse.ProductID = upcse2.ProductID
            GROUP BY upcse2.UserID, upcse2.memberid, upcse2.productid 
            HAVING COUNT(UserID) >= 2
            )
```

So basically I need to add ucpse.ID in the Select statement while keeping DISTINCT values for MemberID,ProductID and UserID.

Any Ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, could you please provide some data and expected output.

Comment: What is the purpose of adding `ucpse.ID`? You are trying to do two somewhat contradictory things. From the sound of things, MemberID, PrdouctID and UserID can all exist in ucpse multiple times with different IDs. Without picking a specific ID, you can't select one ID, MemberID, ProductID and UserID if there are multiple IDs per each MemberID, ProductID, and UserID.

Comment: Because I was lazy at the beginning, I managed myself to have each legit row to be duplicated between 15 and 67 times in the table. So each employee (UserID) will have an amount of commissison paid for each possible product (ProductID) for every of our customer (MemberID). The only unique constraint in this table was on the line ID. The query stated in the question give me exactly what I need to keep. I can delete the rest using DELETE FROM ucpse WHERE ID NOT IN (). But to do this I need to obtain the ID of the line from the DISTINCT query.

Comment: If the data has been duplicated 67 times for a given employee with a given product and a given client, I need to keep only one of thoses records. It's not important which one, so this is why I use DISTINC to obtain unique combinaison of given employee with a given product and a given client.

Comment: But the is no ID of line (singular) from DISTINCT query.  There are one of more ID.  It is non-deterministic which distinct row is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to you comment:
*If the data has been duplicated 67 times for a given employee with a given product and a given client, I need to keep only one of thoses records. It's not important which one, so this is why I use DISTINC to obtain unique combinaison of given employee with a given product and a given client.*

You can use `MIN()` or `MAX()`  and `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT MAX(ucpse.ID) AS ID, ucpse.MemberID, ucpse.ProductID, ucpse.UserID
FROM UserCustomerProductSalaryExceptions as ucpse
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
            FROM UserCustomerProductSalaryExceptions as upcse2 
            WHERE ucpse.userid = upcse2.userid AND ucpse.MemberID = upcse2.MemberID AND ucpse.ProductID = upcse2.ProductID
            GROUP BY upcse2.UserID, upcse2.memberid, upcse2.productid 
            HAVING COUNT(UserID) >= 2
            )

GROUP BY ucpse.MemberID, ucpse.ProductID, ucpse.UserID
```

**UPDATE:**

From you comments I think the below query is what you need

```
DELETE FROM  UserCustomerProductSalaryExceptions
WHERE ID NOT IN  ( SELECT MAX(ucpse.ID) AS ID
                         FROM #UserCustomerProductSalaryExceptions
                         GROUP BY ucpse.MemberID, ucpse.ProductID, ucpse.UserID
                         HAVING COUNT(ucpse.ID) >= 2
                     )
```

Comment: Your approach is working for my needs. I've been able to use MAX(ucpse.ID) and update the rows to set the column "IsValid" to true to then delete the other unwanted data.

Comment: UPDATE UserCustomerProductSalaryExceptions SET Active = 1 WHERE ID IN(
SELECT MAX(ucpse.ID) 
FROM UserCustomerProductSalaryExceptions as ucpse
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
    FROM UserCustomerProductSalaryExceptions as upcse2 
    WHERE ucpse.userid = upcse2.userid AND ucpse.MemberID = upcse2.MemberID AND ucpse.ProductID = upcse2.ProductID
    GROUP BY upcse2.UserID, upcse2.memberid, upcse2.productid 
    HAVING COUNT(UserID) >= 2)
    GROUP BY ucpse.MemberID, ucpse.ProductID, ucpse.UserID)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to delete the duplicates, this will do it:

```
WITH X AS
(SELECT ID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID, ProductID, UserID ORDER BY ID) AS DupRowNum<br
FROM UserCustomerProductSalaryExceptions
)
DELETE X WHERE DupRowNum > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

ID's not necessary - try:

```
UPDATE uu SET
    <your settings here>
FROM UserCustomerProductSalaryExceptions uu
    JOIN ( <paste your entire query above here> 
         ) uc ON uc.MemberID=uu.MemberId AND uc.ProductID=uu.ProductId AND uc.UserID=uu.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of your data structure (which I would STRONGLY advise normalizing as soon as possible), it sounds like you should be updating all the records. It sounds as if each duplicate is important because it contains some information about an employee's relation to a customer or product.

I would probably update all the records. Try this:

```
UPDATE UCPSE 
SET
    --Do your updates here
FROM UserCustomerProductSalaryExceptions as ucpse
JOIN
(
    SELECT UserID, MemberID, ProductID
    FROM UserCustomerProductSalaryExceptions
    GROUP BY UserID, MemberID, ProductID
    HAVING COUNT(UserID) >= 2
) T
ON ucpse.UserID = T.UserID AND ucpse.MemberID = T.MemberID AND ucpse.ProductID = T.ProductID
```

Comment: To normalize my data (this table in particular) I need to add a constraint that allow one unique line per UserID + ProductID + MemberID.

Comment: If you're not going to get rid of the duplicates, then it's best to update all rows where the UserID, ProductID and MemberID match. If these are true duplicates, just pick a row and delete the rest. You are working around a much, much larger problem, the data duplication and poor data structure.